# react hook form doesn't reset my fields correctly

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, controlled-component

I have a controlled form with react hook form.
it contains one input type *search*, two *datepickers* and one *select*.
it only rest correctly the select, but not the other 2 elements.

i declared some *defaultValues*, but if i specify `onClick={() => reset(defaultValues)}` it only resets the internal state of fields but not the displayed values of the fields.

here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-benji-ucvwsb?file=/src/App.js)